# Create a Mobile Agent using Jade for Android

Tags: android, agents-jade

I first heard of [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/) around 4 months back. Recently, I stumbled upon a [link](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f12/jade-android-released-181/) that confirmed the release of `JADE` for `Android`. I have gone through the various `JADE tutorials` for creating agents.

However, I don't know how to go about creating a `mobile agent` for the Android platform.
Can anyone who has worked with JADE in Android, tell me how should I create a simple mobile agent for the Android platform?

Any tutorials , links would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some interesting links for the JADE. They are:

[Google group](http://code.google.com/p/jchat4android/)

another awesome PDF if you want to read into deep:
[PDF](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADE_ANDROID_Guide.pdf)

Comment: I tried it 2 years ago and it work fine. But JADE for Android is obsolete. Maybe JaCa-Android will be good. I use JADE for develop multi-agent systems but agents run on server and its is managed by Android app that is connected with agent via my protocel (over HTTP).